I am using a React Native Input box and below that a submit button to execute some action.But I am unable to click the submit button in 1st attempt
I am using a React Native Input box and below that a submit button to execute some action.But I am unable to click the submit button in 1st attempt.it takes two attempts to click the submit button.In 1st attemt the keyboard is getting closed and then only I am able to submit.
Here the code.
<TextInput
onlyNumeric = {true}
                    showErrorOnFocus = {false}
                    value={inputValue}
                    isFocus= {true}
                    regex= {RegexConfig.MOBILE}
                    type= {InputTypeToken.MOBILE}
       
                    charLimit= {10}
                    keyboardType= {KeyboardTypeToken.numberPad}
                    placeholder= "Enter mobile number"
                    
                    
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{marginTop:8}}>
                <Button
                    
                    label = {'Continue'}
                    onPress = {() => {}}
                />
            </View>

